# Modularizing matplolib graphing based on a data dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

For plotting I often use a dictionary that contains my data of interest, regarding my numerical simulations. For example I have a `numpy array` let's call it `U` the contains a discretization of a equation in every simulation timestep. Simply put, my `U` is a 2D `np.array` where each row is a given timestep (first row first time step) and each column is a spatial discretization. For example:

```
U = np.array([ [ 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.25, 0 ],
               [ 0.125, 0.225, 0.3, 0.225, 0.125 ],
               [ 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2] ])
```

Hence, U[0] is the initial positions, U[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpLeW.png) is the first iteration, U[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HViBh.png) the last one, of course, is easy to get to thousands timesteps, lets move from here, since isn't important how `U` (or any simulation) is calculated.

Each simulation is packed in a "data structure" dictionary to guide the plotting, that contains some key information as: `x_data` spatial discretization, `y_data` functions evaluated in each point in spatial discretization in all time steps (The `U` above), data limits `x_lim`, `y_lim`, if I want to set them, `label` that is what `y_data` is related to, `title` a title to my graph, `linestyle` matplotlib linestyle, `color` color to plot this data. For example:

```
# These were pre-calculated somewhere else in code
V_x_support = np.linspace(...)
V_t_support = np.linspace(...)
V = np.array(...)

# Here starts the data to plot
ts_range = (0,3000,300)      # I just want to pick some data to graph

V_dataplots = []
for pos in np.arange(*ts_range):
data = {
        'x_data': V_x_support,
        'y_data': V[pos],
        'x_lim': [-1, 1],
        'y_lim': [-1, 1],
        'label': f'{V_t_support[pos]:.3g} s',
        'title': f'{V_t_support[pos]:.3g} s',
        'linestyle': '--',
        'color': '.4',
       }
```

Once I calculated some arrays, I would love to compare them using matplotlib, but I hate to repeat myself, hence I started to write functions to make the drawings, where I can just pass to my plot function

```
fig = panelize(
    data = [V_dataplots],
    plot_function = single_plot, 
    title = 'V Mimetic 4th order',
    labely='Velocity',
    labelx='Position',
    sharex=True,
    sharey=True
)
```

This will pick my manually chosen positions in time and plot it in a panel. The function to do the panels and the plots are below.

How can I reduce the number o lines, keeping the code more cleaner and more readable while avoiding to repeat myself. There are any good MatPlotLib techniques to handle this?

First two examples of the image output

[image: single plot]

[image: compare plot]

```
# TODO:
#   - If a panelized axes do not have associated data to plot it will
#     not configure the axes and therefor will not be "prettified"
#     need to fix this (or remove at all the not drawn plots).
#
#   - Draw legend only if some plot has set a label, how to do this? 
#
#   - Make the font scale with less plots are drawn, less axes, bigger
#     fonts.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=mpl.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)


def get_axes_diagonal(ax):
    axes_limits = list(map(ax.transData.transform, zip(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim())))
    return np.linalg.norm(axes_limits[1] - axes_limits[0])


def countour_every(ax, every, x_data, y_data,
        color='black', linestyle='-', marker='o', **kwargs):
    """Draw a line with countour marks at each every points"""

    ax_diag_size = get_axes_diagonal(ax)
    diag_ratio = np.round(ax_diag_size/150, 1)
    lw = .5*diag_ratio                  # line width
    ms = 2*diag_ratio                   # Marker size

    # Some variable parameters
    every=int(len(x_data)/every)

    line, = ax.plot(x_data, y_data, linestyle)
    line.set_linewidth(lw)
    line.set_color(color)

    mark, = ax.plot(x_data, y_data, marker)
    mark.set_markevery(every)
    mark.set_markersize(ms)
    mark.set_color('white')

    contour, = ax.plot(x_data, y_data, marker)
    contour.set_markevery(every)
    contour.set_markersize(ms)
    contour.set_color(color)
    contour.set_fillstyle('none')
    contour.set_markeredgewidth(lw)

    return line


def prettify_axes(ax, data):
    """Makes my plot pretty"""

    ax_diag_size = get_axes_diagonal(ax)

    # Some variable parameters
    diag_ratio = np.round(ax_diag_size/150, 1)
    lw = .5*diag_ratio                  # line width
    slw = 2*lw                          # spine line width
    ln = 3*diag_ratio                   # Tick length

    # Set spines
    ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(slw)
    ax.spines['right'].set_linewidth(slw)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(slw)
    ax.spines['top'].set_linewidth(slw)

    if 'x_label' in data:
        ax.set_xlabel(data['x_label'])

    if 'y_label' in data:
        ax.set_ylabel(data['y_label'])

    if 'title' in data:
        ax.set_title(data['title'])

    if 'y_lim' in data:
        ax.set_ylim(data['y_lim'])

    if 'x_lim' in data:
        ax.set_xlim(data['x_lim'])

    # Draw legend only if labels were set (HOW TO DO IT?)
    # ax.get_legend_handles_labels() <-- maybe this can help
    # if ax("has_some_label_set"):
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size': 6})

    ax.title.set_fontsize(7)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(width=lw)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in')
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=ln)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(zorder=0)
    ax.xaxis.label.set_size(7)

    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=lw)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in')
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=ln)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(zorder=0)
    ax.yaxis.label.set_size(7)


def scale_loglog(ax, data):
    """Set a plot to loglog scale"""


def prettify_second_axes(ax):

    ax_diag_size = get_axes_diagonal(ax)

    # Some variable parameters
    diag_ratio = np.round(ax_diag_size/150, 1)
    lw = .5*diag_ratio                  # line width
    slw = 2*lw                          # spine line width
    ln = 3*diag_ratio                   # Tick length

    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=6)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(width=lw)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in')
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=ln)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(zorder=0)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelcolor='red')
    ax.yaxis.label.set_size(7)


def compare_plot(ax, data):
    """Compare two plots and also gives the difference

    optional:
        show difference or not
        difference axis independent or not
    """
    ax_diag_size = get_axes_diagonal(ax)

    line1 = countour_every(ax, 10, **data[0])
    line2 = countour_every(ax, 10, **data[1])

    if 'label' in data[0]:
        line1.set_label(data[0]['label'])

    if 'label' in data[1]:
        line2.set_label(data[1]['label'])

    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    line3 = ax2.plot(
            data[0]['x_data'], 
            data[0]['y_data']-data[1]['y_data'], '-',
            color='red', alpha=.2, zorder=1, label='Diff')

    prettify_axes(ax, data[0])
    prettify_second_axes(ax2)

def single_plot(ax, data):
    """Plot a line data"""
    if isinstance(data, (list,tuple)):
        data = data[0]

    ax_diag_size = get_axes_diagonal(ax)

    line = countour_every(ax, 10, **data)

    if 'label' in data:
        line.set_label(data['label'])

    prettify_axes(ax, data)


def panelize(data, plot_function, 
        title=None, labelx=None, labely=None,
        sharex=False, sharey=False):
    """Put a group of data into a square panel"""


    if isinstance(data[0], (list, tuple)):
        ndata = len(data)
        nplots = len(data[0])
    else:
        ndata = 1
        nplots = len(data)

    # Wider than taller
    ncols = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(nplots)))
    nrows = int(np.ceil(nplots/ncols))

    # Use grid instead subplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey)

    # Calculate the panel distribution and size
    max_width = 6
    width_per_plot = max_width / ncols
    height_ratio = 1 
    height_per_plot = height_ratio*width_per_plot
    max_height = nrows*height_per_plot
    fig.set_size_inches(max_width,max_height)

    for n, (ax, d) in enumerate(zip(np.atleast_1d(axes).flatten(),zip(*data))): 
        plot_function(ax, d)

    if title is not None:
        fig.suptitle(title)
        fig.set_tight_layout({'rect': [0, 0.03, 1, 0.95]})
    else:
        fig.set_tight_layout(True) 

    if sharex and labelx:
        fig.text(0.5, 0.04, labelx, ha='center')

    if sharey and labely:
        fig.text(0.01, 0.5, labely, va='center', rotation='vertical')


    return fig
```